# How to make osd volume widget smoth on ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: virtualization, volume-control, notify-osd, widgets, animations

OSD widget shifts from left to right while I am changing sound volume. Please write how to fix it. I d like to make it more pixel perfect like on Mac OS.

[image: Converted Image.gif]

Source: https://media.giphy.com/media/Sx4XPuRmuXdiwdyxi6/giphy.gif

Comment: You might need to file a bug against `notify-osd`.  From a terminal window run `ubuntu-bug notify-osd` to file a bug.  There are several bugs filed that are listed in https://wiki.ubuntu.com/NotifyOSD but I am not seeing one for motion when the OSD is up.

Comment: Thank you Terrance. 
I've sent report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/notify-osd/+bug/1857672

Comment: I have realized that the reason of this tremble was resolution. Defalt was 16x9 (1920x1080) i ve change it to 16x9 (1600x900). On the default resolution it works smoth